# how to apply an index to a dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I can't seem to figure out how to build a dataframe from a series of new dataframes which all have the same index ( date ). I have the creation of the destination dataframe working properly BUT it's the changing of the index from 0...n to the dates that has me stumped.

I am building a dataframe
**df_new_sym**

and adding it as a column to another dataframe

**df_all_sym**

this will continue for as many new columns are needed.

```
**df_new_sym**
          date              iv_close_abs
0   2020-03-11         7.695
1   2020-03-12        22.172
2   2020-03-13        -8.108
3   2020-03-16        26.308
```

will CURRENTLY result in

```
**df_all_sym**
      type_a   type_b
0    7.695     10.00
1   22.172     11.23
2   -8.108     14.78
3   26.308      9.98
```

I want the index of df_all_sym to be the date range coming from df_new_sym.

```
     date      type_a   type_b
2020-03-11     7.695     10.00
2020-03-12     22.172     11.23
2020-03-13     -8.108     14.78
2020-03-16     26.308      9.98
```

Comment: Please show your code, because I cannot guess what you did...

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the relevant code

Comment: I had to remove the code as it was confusing people. I have the df_all_sym building correctly it's the INDEX problem that has me stumped

Answer (score 3):

just try the below code. It may solve the issue

```
df_all_sym = pd.merge(df_new_sym,df_all_sym,left_on='iv_close_abs',right_on='type_a',how='left')
```

followed by

`df_all_sym = df_all_sym.set_index('date')`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear what the problem is. I can create the df_all_sym columns from the df_new_sym  and that works fine. What is NOT happening is that the INDEX of df_all_sym should be the index of df_all_sym. I had tried setting the set_index approach but it doesn't work.

Comment: I changed the question to "hopefully" clarify the problem. It's the INDEX not the df_all_sym creation that's the issue.